# Fluid Mechanics - Honey flow inside pipe

Tags: fluid-dynamics

Honey initially at rest in a tube starts flowing down at  = 0 s due to gravity, eventually reaching steady state. The equation governing the transient velocity profile of the honey is [equation of motion honey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ryEI.png).

The no-slip condition requires that the velocity of the honey is zero at the radius of the tube, . The goal is to write a script that will calculate the velocity profile as a function of  and .

So far I found the following: 
IC = v(0) = 0;
BC1 = v(R, inf) = 0 (no slip condition);

However, could anyone confirm if this second boundary condition is right?
BC2 = dv/dt(R, inf) = 0; (maximum velocity inside the pipe)

Thank you in advance.

[schematic of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7Nvk.png)